# How to traverse through an array of JSON in javascript? and use it to populate <option> element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this array of JSON and I want to loop through them and use it to fill up my `option` element.

**Sample Array:**

```
var myOptionData = [
          {fooValue:"1", fooText:"option A"},
          {fooValue:"2", fooText:"option B"},
          {fooValue:"3", fooText:"option C"}
]
```

**I did use this method:**

```
var fields="";

 fields += "</select >";

        fields += "<option  value='0'></option>";
        $.each(myOptionData , function (key, value) {
            fields += "<option value=" + value.fooValue + ">" + value.fooText + "</option>";
        });
        fields += "</select >";
```

//But I want to make it more flexible, so that I can reuse it in making another `<option>` from another array of JSON, like this scenario:

```
var myNewOptionData = [
          {myValue:"5", myText:"option E"},
          {myValue:"6", myText:"option F"},
          {myValue:"7", myText:"option G"},
          {myValue:"8", myText:"option H"}
]
```

//Now I cannot use the method above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply turn the whole operation into a function:

```js
function mkSelect(data){
  return "<select><option  value='0'></option>"
   + data.map(o=>{
      let [val,txt]=Object.values(o);
      return "<option value=" + val + ">" + txt + "</option>"}).join("") 
   + "</select >";
}
const myOptionData = [
      {fooValue:"1", fooText:"option A"},
      {fooValue:"2", fooText:"option B"},
      {fooValue:"3", fooText:"option C"}
], 
  myNewOptionData = [
      {myValue:"5", myText:"option E"},
      {myValue:"6", myText:"option F"},
      {myValue:"7", myText:"option G"},
      {myValue:"8", myText:"option H"}
];

document.querySelector("#frm").innerHTML=mkSelect(myOptionData)+"<br>"
   +mkSelect(myNewOptionData);
```

```html
<form id="frm"></form>
```

The function should be improved, as it momentarily relies on the sequence of the properties of object `o`. Maybe the property names could be checked for containing "Value" and "Text"?

Here is a slight variation of my snippet, checking for parts of the property names. Now the order of the given option properties is immaterial and a selected option can also be defined by providing a property that contains "select" in its name:

```js
function mkSelect(data){
  const arr=data.map(o=>Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).map(([k,v])=>
       [k.replace(/.*value.*/i,"val")        // generate an object with standardised key names:
         .replace(/.*text.*/i,"txt")         // ===> val, txt and sel
         .replace(/.*select.*/i,"sel"),
        v])));
  return "<select><option value='0'></option>"  // build the actual select element:
        +arr.map(o=>`<option value="${o.val}"${o.sel?` selected="${o.sel}"`:""}>${o.txt}</option>`).join("")+"</select>"
}
const myOptionData = [
      {fooValue:"1", fooText:"option A"},
      {fooValue:"2", fooText:"option B", thisIsSelected: true},
      {fooValue:"3", fooText:"option C"},
      {thisTextIsGreatToo:"option D", andValueThis:"4"}
], 
  myNewOptionData = [
      {myValue:"5", myText:"option E"},
      {myValue:"6", myText:"option F"},
      {myValue:"7", myText:"option G"},
      {selectThis: 1, myLastText:"option H", myLastValue:"8"}
];

document.querySelector("#frm").innerHTML=mkSelect(myOptionData)+"<br>"+mkSelect(myNewOptionData)
```

```html
<form id="frm"></form>
```

Comment: Yes, only just noticed it and I changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when making a function you should expect to receive parameters with defined keys. There's nothing wrong with requiring objects within lists to have fooValue & fooText. However if you want to make it property-independent:

```js
    function createSelect(options, valueName, textName) {
      const select = `<select><option value='0'></option>
      ${options.map(option => `<option value="${option[valueName]}">${option[textName]}</option>`)}
      </select>`;

      return select;
    }

    console.log(
      createSelect([{randomValue: 1, randomName: 'Go select!'}], 'randomValue', 'randomName')
    );
```

Note how jQuery isn't necessary in this case.
Map is a function that transforms every item on your list (without modifying it)

Also if you want to 'just specify the keys once and then reuse' you can create partially applied functions:

```js
const createSelect = (valueName, textName) => (options)=> {
      return `<select><option value='0'></option>
      ${options.map(option => `<option value="${option[valueName]}">${option[textName]}</option>`)}
      </select>`;
    }
    
    const fooList = [{fooValue: 1, fooName: 'Foo select!'}];
    
    const fooSelect = createSelect('fooValue', 'fooName');

    console.log(
      fooSelect(fooList) 
    );
    
    const barList = [{barValue: 2, barName: 'Bar select!'}];
    
    const barSelect = createSelect('barValue', 'barName');

    console.log(
      barSelect(barList) 
    );
```